# TDE enabled database backup taking too long

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, transparent-data-encryption

We have recently implemented TDE and backup compression is also enabled. Before TDE backup used to take about 20min but now it takes about one hour.

I have set `@MaxTransferSize` to 3MB, 2MB, 1MB and 0.5MB but didn't make any difference time wise, database is 90GB of size and it is SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU4.

We using Ola's Maintenance Solution/Scripts to backup the database. Any idea why it is taking 3x longer when TDE enabled please?

Comment: There were lot of fixes and enhancement related to TDE and backup compression in SQL Server 2016 Sp1 and Sp2. You are at RTM CU4, before anything I would suggest you to apply SQL Server 2016 SP2 ASAP. Please also read [Backup Compression For TDE Enabled DB](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/06/20/sqlsweet16-episode-1-backup-compression-for-tde-enabled-databases/). This blog tells you how to extract maximum when using TDE and backup compression together

Comment: @Shanky we aren't at RTM CU4 but SP1 CU4.

Comment: Are you backing up on a network share? How big were the backups before TDE and how big are they now? Any other changes in addition to the TDE?

Comment: By any chance, you are backing up to the same media using INIT but not using FORMAT ? Use FORMAT and see if it is still slow or not. Also, update to [latest SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4135048/cumulative-update-1-for-sql-server-2016-sp2) since you are using TDE and there was a known bug which corrupts the database `FIX: TDE enabled database backup with compression causes database corruption in SQL Server 2016`

Comment: @Sajid ok, but still I would suggest you to apply SP2. Plus the link I shared has some information which would help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reduced the time to 28min now, changed @MaxTransferSize= 524288 to 262144 and also removed @Verify='Y' parameter which did the trick.

I believe backup @Verify option was the real issue here, as soon as I removed the option backup time cut to half.